# normal law and unitary matrices

Tags: normal-distribution

I need to prove the following but I don't know how:

> Admit Y ~ N($\mu$,$U^t$$\Sigma$U) where $\Sigma$ is
>   a diagonal matrix containing positive elements and U is a unitary matrix.
>
> Show that UY ~ N(U$\mu$,$\Sigma$)

Should I proceed using the Gaussian multivariate definition or there is a quicker way of solving it?

Thank you very much in advance.

James

`

Comment: Since $Y$ is Gaussian, then $UY$ is also Gaussian, hence it is totally determined by its mean and covariance. Compute those and compare with your desired form.

Comment: With this method I do achieve that E[UY] = E[U]E[Y] = U$\mu$ However the variance Var[UY] = $U^2$ Var[Y] = U$\Sigma$U != $\Sigma$ !
Where is my mistake ?

Comment: you need to treat $Y$ as a vector and compute all cross correlations $YxY$